# Replace with first occurrence value for duplicate columns using pandas or python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like

```
ca ca ca 120.00

ca cc cd 130.00

ca ca ca 135.23

ca ha ca 60.00

ca ha ca 50.00
```

If first 3 columns are equal then fourth column value should be the first occurrence. I want data like

```
ca ca ca 120.00

ca cc cd 130.00

ca ca ca 120.00

ca ha ca 60.00

ca ha ca 60.00
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: Well that depends, first question I'll ask is, in what shape or form is the original data? is it a dict, a list, a CSV?

Comment: thanks for response. It is a text file

Comment: I have a data in a text file. Each column is separated with single space. I have around more than thousand lines in a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)

Dynamic solution with selecting first 3 columns to list and processing 4th column assigned back:

```
df.iloc[:, 3] = df.groupby(df.columns[:3].tolist())[df.columns[3]].transform('first')
print (df)
    0   1   2      3
0  ca  ca  ca  120.0
1  ca  cc  cd  130.0
2  ca  ca  ca  120.0
3  ca  ha  ca   60.0
4  ca  ha  ca   60.0
```

If there are 4 columns names like `a,b,c,d` solution is simplier:

```
df['d'] = df.groupby(['a','b','c'])['d'].transform('first')
print (df)
    a   b   c      d
0  ca  ca  ca  120.0
1  ca  cc  cd  130.0
2  ca  ca  ca  120.0
3  ca  ha  ca   60.0
4  ca  ha  ca   60.0
```

Comment: First link is dead! :(

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['ca', 'ca', 'ca', 120.00], ['ca', 'cc', 'cd', 130.00], ['ca', 'ca', 'ca', 135.23], ['ca', 'ha', 'ca', 60.00], ['ca', 'ha', 'ca', 50.00]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Let's construct a res_df, where only column A = Column b = Column C

```
res_df = df[(df['a'] == df['b']) & (df['a'] == df['c'])]
```

Let's get unique results from result set.

```
unique_vals = res_df['a'].unique()
```

Now let's loop these values.
Step 1: getting the array of indices of the same type
Step 2: get the value of column D of the first index that is get_indx[0] i.e. 0th position

> df.loc[get_indx[0], 'd']

Step 3: set it to the original df from get_index[1:] i.e poition 1 till end

> df.at[get_indx[i], 'd']

```
for value in unique_vals:
    get_indx = res_df[res_df['a'] == value].index

    if len(get_indx) > 1:
        for i in range(1, len(get_indx)):
            df.at[get_indx[i], 'd'] = df.loc[get_indx[0], 'd']
```