# Panda dataframe nan replacements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am newbie in pandas. So please bear with me.

I have this dataframe:

```
Name,Year,Engine,Price

Car1,2001,100 CC,1000

Car2,2002,150 CC,2000

Car1,2001,100 CC,nan
Car1,2001,100 CC,100
```

I can't figure out how to change the `nan` or `null` value of `“Car 1" + Year+ "100 CC”` from `nan` to `1000`.

I need to extract the value of “Price” while combining “Name +Year + Engine”. And replace where its null.

There are numbers of rows in the csv file which have the null “Price” while combining “Name + Engine”, however in some rows same “Name + Year+ Engine “ has “Price” association with it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace with first occurrence value for duplicate columns using pandas or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64999667/replace-with-first-occurrence-value-for-duplicate-columns-using-pandas-or-python)

Comment: From the suggested duplicate, try: `df['Price'] = df.groupby(['Name','Engine'])['Price'].transform('first')`.

Comment: That is replacing the existing non null values also. I need only null values of "Price" needs to be replaced with existing/present "name +year + engine" which has price.

Answer (score 0):

With the update of your question (an extra row with `Price == 100`, where `Name == Car` and `Engine == 100 CC`), the *logic* behind the choice for filling the `NaN` value in this group with `1000.0` has become ambiguous. Let's add yet another row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': {0: 'Car1', 1: 'Car2', 2: 'Car1', 3: 'Car1', 4: 'Car1'}, 
        'Year': {0: 2001, 1: 2002, 2: 2001, 3: 2001, 4: 2001}, 
        'Engine': {0: '100 CC', 1: '150 CC', 2: '100 CC', 3: '100 CC', 4: '100 CC'}, 
        'Price': {0: 1000.0, 1: 2000.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 100.0, 4: np.nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

   Name  Year  Engine   Price
0  Car1  2001  100 CC  1000.0
1  Car2  2002  150 CC  2000.0
2  Car1  2001  100 CC     NaN
3  Car1  2001  100 CC   100.0
4  Car1  2001  100 CC     NaN
```

In this case, what should happen with the second associated `NaN` value? If you want to fill *all* `NaNs` with the *first* value, you could limit the assignment to the rows that contain `NaNs` by combining [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`pd.Series.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html). This way you'll only overwrite the `NaNs`:

```
df.loc[df['Price'].isna(),'Price'] = df.groupby(['Name','Engine'])\
    ['Price'].transform('first')

print(df)
   Name  Year  Engine   Price
0  Car1  2001  100 CC  1000.0
1  Car2  2002  150 CC  2000.0
2  Car1  2001  100 CC  1000.0
3  Car1  2001  100 CC   100.0
4  Car1  2001  100 CC  1000.0
```

But you can of course change the function (here: "first") passed to [`DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html). E.g. use "max" for `1000.0`, if you are selecting it because it is the highest value. Or if you want the mode, you could do: `.transform(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])` (and get 100.0 in this case!); or get "mean" (`550.0`), "last" (`100`) etc.

More likely, you would want to use [`df.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), i.e. "forward fill", to propagate the last valid value forward. So, fill first `NaN` with `1000.0`, and the second with `100.0`. If so, use:

```
df['Price'] = df.groupby(['Name','Engine'])['Price'].transform('ffill')

print(df)

   Name  Year  Engine   Price
0  Car1  2001  100 CC  1000.0
1  Car2  2002  150 CC  2000.0
2  Car1  2001  100 CC  1000.0
3  Car1  2001  100 CC   100.0
4  Car1  2001  100 CC   100.0
```

Comment: @panda_newbie: If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.